# Which movie first did the chase sequence/pane of glass gag?

Tags: first-appearance, trope, origin

There's a common gag/cliche/trope/whatever in chase sequences in movies/tv/cartoons where two people are carrying a window/mirror/pane of glass across a road that gets smashed during the chase.  In which movie did this first appear?

Comment: Wow...gonna be early. Mack Sennett probably was involved somewhere.

Comment: Have we already had questions about the fruit cart and the yowling cat too?